# Scrapyng AngularJS with Selenium in Python in Chrome headless mode

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I want to crawl information from a webpage which is made with angularjs.

My problem is, that if I crawl the page in "--headless" mode I do not receive my target element. Without "--headless" everything works fine.
May somebody can explain or point a link what are the differences to "--headless"?

I red http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/ . What else could be the matter?

Thank you for any hints.

EDIT:
It also doesn't work with wait conditions in headless mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me after some research, reading:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/665

https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/

The headless request is detected, so one has to set arguments hiding headless mode:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--lang=de-DE')
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"')

options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
```

Comment: I was missing the --lang flag. That made the trick!! Thank you